# How to get data from table to another when you can't re-order columns

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Having trouble putting this into words, reading countless threads describing issues similar to mine, but not this exact one. So here's a super simplified version of what I need done.

I have numbers that correspond to countries in the first table. I have that same list of countries on another table, but without the numbers. **The countries can not be re-ordered in any way on either table.** I want Cell F3 to find the number that's in the cell to the left of "Norway" in Table 1, and put it in F3. Then drag that formula down for the whole table.

It seems so simple but I just can't figure it out.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/169472/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results, instead of a screenshot. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. There are two answers. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Use `vlookup()` with an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), like this:

```
=arrayformula( iferror( vlookup(G3:G13, { D3:D13, C3:C13 }, 2, false) ) )
```

See [vlookup()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093318) and [GFCGlobal](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/creating-simple-formulas/1/).

Comment: Will try that, but I found another way that worked as well.

=INDEX($C$3:$C$13, MATCH(G3, $D$3:$D$13, 0))

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out:

=INDEX($C$3:$C$13, MATCH(G3, $D$3:$D$13, 0))

Comment: From [answer]. "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." By the other hand, in consideration of the help effort done by the poster of the previous answer it would be nice how do you compare this formula to the previous formula.